# AWS Provider terraform apply provider.aws.region

Tags: terraform

***AWS Provider  terraform apply***

Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

- `provider.aws: Invalid AWS Region: us-east-1a`

Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

- `provider.aws: Invalid AWS Region: us-east-1a`

terraform is not applying

Comment: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8560

Answer (score 2):

Your region should not specify an availability zone. Use `us-east-1` instead.